# How to add h1, h2 and h3 headings to RichText widget?

Tags: html-heading, impresspages

I work with Impresspages 4 and I want to know how I can add h1,h2 and h3 addings to the RichText Widget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look how other TinyMCE related plugins are implemented

http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/?q=tinymce

And do your own customizations to TinyMCE config. The default config can be found in Ip/Internal/Core/assets/tinymce/default.js

'valid_elements' is the setting that you want to append with h1, h2, h3 tags. And add Header select tool to the toolbar1. You will likely need to refer to the TinyMCE configuration guide.